# PHP_ can't echo or print another language text

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to print or echo another language text, but it is not working!!!
I tried utf8 encoding or decoding but it doesn't work!
Can someone help?
thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>zura</title>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   include 'includes/connection.php';

   $query = "SELECT * FROM chiragdani.children;";
   mysql_select_db('chiragdani',$conn);
   $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
          print "<p>". mb_substr($rows['ChildID'], 0, 10000, "UTF-8").'      '.$rows    ['ChildName'].$rows['ChildLastName'].'         '."</p>" ;
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the encoding you have defined for your HTML?

Comment: thank for your reply but it doesn't work...

Comment: It is possible that your OS/Browser does not support the language.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon really?

Comment: Is your file actually saved in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Is your DB connection in UTF-8? Is your database? Your columns? Your data? You'd be able to define this way easier if you didn't use the deprecated `mysql_` functions, but rather PDO.

Comment: No it supports see my edited question. In php when I wrote header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  it worked for the example. But for this code it isn't working.

Comment: you can't send the header after html output

Comment: @hek2mgl you can if output buffering is turned on I am pretty sure

Comment: And what should I do if not mysql_?  I am new in php...  Is there another way to do the same things?

Comment: @user2971569 MySQLi or PDO. Also, what if you set the content-type to use ISO instead: `charset=ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon This comment is off topic here, as output buffering is obviously not used. In the current form the header() usage will lead to a warning

Comment: I just *!&% love it when an OP changes a question `midstream` with added code "after the fact". Hence, my downvoted answer. Google the *!@$ thing.

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree about off topic, however it is not the cause of the issue. He would be getting a whole new world of errors if it wasn't. To sum it up OB must be on in the php.ini

Comment: Voted to close this question because of too many edits "after the fact" and lack of research.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Hey you are right ! :)  missed that, one can enable output buffering in the php.ini.. Seems it is not so obvious. Also it is not the cause of the problem, that's true

Comment: @BenM It still does the same.

Comment: [please read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<?PHP
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 echo 'ягвфцвб';
?>
```

Written with Notepad++ (Encoding: UTF-8 without BOM)

Edit:

Do you have something like this in your  `connection.php`?

```
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",$connection);
```

Comment: `header()` won't work for the OP. He has output before it...

Comment: OP? he had to write header('...') before any html code I think.

Comment: If he has output buffering on it should be fine..

Comment: OP = original poster. You should add a note about the need to include `header()` before output is started.

Comment: Also saving without BOM is an important thing to remember... damn IE..

Comment: This worked fine when I added inside php this:  header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');           but in second code it doesn't work...

Comment: I can't see how this got 2 upvotes, it's hardly any different than mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I upvoted for the importance of the 'without BOM'. IE throws crazy errors if you do not do this as it does not support UTF properly. I know IE7 does this - not sure about 8..

Comment: +1 for `SET NAMES utf8`

Comment: Exactly, without BOM plays some mean tricks. UTF-8 is the trickiest to deal with and there are too many factors at play when it comes to this, DB etc. @MichaelCoxon The OP changed his/her question, from 3 lines of code, to a full DB-related code. I should have known, and should have waited 5-10 minutes after the question was posted. Teaches me right, I'll know better next time.

Comment: @Wikunia You are right about `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",$connection);` I myself use `$con->set_charset("utf8");` since I am using `mysqli_*` functions. I did not appreciate the OP changing his/her question from the initial **3 lines of code**, to a full-fledged DB-related issue. You deserve the votes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know why we all got downvotes after a second... kind of a creepy discussion here :D but I hope we could both help the OP

Comment: Me neither, I don't know. Yet am under the impression that some may have thought that we should have further researched this, and I do agree on that, "IF" that is the case, but again, OP only showed 3 lines of code at first. By the way, you say you saved "without" BOM. When I saved "without", gave me `ÑÐ³Ð²Ñ„Ñ†Ð²Ð±` but when saved "with" BOM, characters displayed correctly. @Wikunia

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is weird which browser do you use? and you use Notepad++ as well?

Comment: Yes I use Notepad++ also. My browser is FF, the latest version, what is your browser? @Wikunia

Comment: Ok, I see what the differences are. I used what you have in your answer `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and saved without BOM and it is OK. Yet, in order for it to be displayed properly without the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, then one would need to save it WITH BOM. @Wikunia

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I voted to close this question because of too many edits "after the fact" and lack of research. The OP changed the question from 3 lines of code, to a DB-related issue.

---

Your file needs to be **saved as** `UTF-8` (with BOM)

Using Windows Notepad, will save it as ANSI automatically and will not display those characters.

Therefore, using an editor such as [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) wil let you save as UTF-8

Upon testing your code using ANSI, did not display them, but when "saved as" UTF-8 did display them correctly.

---

Edit (2):

As `Wikunia` states in the answer, `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",$connection);` and it  should be noted that it is to be used "before" querying the database.

However, if data was initially entered "without" the use of UTF-8, then that could be an issue.

I myself use something to this effect: (with success)

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$con->query("UPDATE table SET  column_name = '$variable'");
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with file encoding (he's not typing the content), it's dynamic from a DB.

Comment: when I am doing this: <?PHP
echo 'ягвфцвб';
?>

Comment: it works fine but I think problem is in variables...

Comment: The OP changed the question and only had 3 lines of code. I hate it when somebody pulls stunts like that. @BenM

Comment: So how does this question differ from the other one that got 2 upvotes?

Comment: Your data may need to be initially saved in DB as UTF-8. You can't expect DB to automatically translate something it doesn't know how to deal with from the start. @user2971569